# Populate form values from database Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to fetch data from the database to update and save. I can add the data. Since I am trying to do this in class view I don't know how to use generic. Update view and grab the entry by the id. Here is the FormView I use to submit the data

```
class CompanyView(generic.FormView):
    form_class = CompanyForm
    template_name = 'company/company.html'
    
    success_url = '/company'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

I listed the details by adding an edit button to each entry and wrote a view like the same one but stuck with populating the data with the corresponding id.

How can I modify this to make the edit?

Answer (score 2):

If you specify a URL pattern that contains a field named `pk`:

```
from app_name.views import CompanyUpdateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('edit/<int:pk>/', CompanyUpdateView.as_view(), name='company-update')
]
```

Then you can work with an `UpdateView` that will make updates to the item with the primary key:

```
from django.views.generic import UpdateView

class CompanyUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Company
    form_class = CompanyForm
    template_name = 'company/company.html'
    success_url = '/company'
```

This view will fetch the relevant `Company` from the database, populate the form with the data, and when a POST request is made, update the corresponding `Company`.

Comment: How can I use the corresponding pk for getting individual db entries for eg if I am listing an edit button to each entries like this `<li>{{ company.company_name}} - <button type='button'<a {% url  %}> Edit </a></li>`

Comment: You can use `a href="{% url 'company-update' pk=company.pk %}"` with `company-update the name you defined for the `CompanyUpdateView`.

Comment: I didnt understand the last part. Is that name of the app ?

Comment: @GaiusGD'cruz: no the `name=...` of the `path(...)`.